# Limit Access Token for G Suite Directory API to a specific OU

Tags: google-admin-sdk

We're developing an API to create and delete users on G Suite.

I would like to restrict this API to manage users only in a specific organization unit, not on the whole directory.

Anyone knows a way to implement this restriction?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you elaborate a little on what you have tried or post the code you have implemented so far? Are you creating your own API on top of the Admin SDK API?

Answer (score 0):

**You can create a user with Admin privileges restricted to one Organizational Unit with custom roles**

https://support.google.com/a/answer/6129577?hl=en

By going here:
https://admin.google.com/u/0/ac/roles

You can create a custom role to manage Users, for example. Then when you go into the custom role you have made, and assign someone to that role, you will see the option to limit that role to one organizational unit.

(I assume that your API users authenticate with Google).